# Fetching volume number in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am running PS cmdlet `get-customcmdlet` which is generating following output

```
Name                         FreeSpaceGB
----                         -----------
ABC-vol001                   1,474.201
ABC-vol002                   2,345.437     
ABC-vol003                   3,147.135
random-value                 4,147.135
```

I want to capture `003` from the highest `volume number` `ABC-vol003`  I also want to ignore `random-value` and only want to consider the values which have `vol` in it

```
get-customcmdlet | select Name 

Name              
----          
ABC-vol001   
ABC-vol001      
ABC-vol001
random-value
```

Here, I want `003` to be variable based upon highest volume number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a custom sort, and select the last item, like:

```
Get-CustomCmdlet | Sort {$_.Name -replace '.*?(\d+)$','$1'} | Select -Last 1
```

**Edit:** It looked like you already knew how to use `Where`, since you had that in your question before you edited it out, but you can use that to only get volumes that have 'vol' in the name, then sort those...

```
Get-CustomCmdlet | Where{$_.Name -match '-vol\d+'} | Sort {$_.Name -replace '.*?(\d+)$','$1'} | Select -Last 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I have made a small update to my question. can you please answer accordingly

Comment: Doesn't add much, but you can also use `... -descending | Select -First 1`.

Comment: I am getting `random-value                 4,147.135` as an output. I want to ignore all `random-value` and include only which have `vol` within it

Comment: I am able to achieve it by using `select Name | Where-Object Name -match vol`