# Filtering out only specific values in PS output

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am running PS cmdlet `get-customcmdlet` which is generating following output

```
Name                         FreeSpaceGB
----                         -----------
ABC-vol001                   1,474.201
ABC-vol002                   2,345.437     
ABC-vol003                   3,147.135
ABC-volDAV                   4,147.135
ABC-volCDA                   5,147.135
```

I want to capture `003` from the highest `volume number` `ABC-vol003`  I also want to ignore values that don't have have integer value after `vol` in it such as `ABC-volDAV` and only want to consider the values which have integer value after `vol` in it

I am using the following cmdlet but it is generating wrong output `ABC-volDAV`

```
Get-CustomCmdlet | Where-Object Name -match vol | select Name | Sort {$_.Name -replace '.*?(\d+)$','$1'} -descending |  Select -First 1
```

My output should be `ABC-vol003`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stripping value in PS and comparing if it is an integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51937717/stripping-value-in-ps-and-comparing-if-it-is-an-integer-value)

Comment: Was there something wrong with my edited answer to your previous (virtually identical) question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51936755/3245749)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
$inputData = @"
"Name","FreeSpaceGB"
"ABC-vol001","1474.201"
"ABC-vol002","2345.437"     
"ABC-vol003","3147.135"
"ABC-volDAV","4147.135"
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$inputData |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -match '-vol[\d]+' } |
  Sort-Object { [Int] $_.FreeSpaceGB } -Descending |
  Select-Object -First 1
```

The above outputs this:

```
Name       FreeSpaceGB
----       -----------
ABC-vol003 3147.135
```

Based on the comments - here's another attempt to guess at what the questioner wants to do:

```
$inputData = @"
"Name","FreeSpaceGB"
"ABC-vol001","1474.201"
"ABC-vol002","2345.437"     
"ABC-vol003","3147.135"
"ABC-volDAV","4147.135"
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$inputData |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -match '-vol[\d]+' } |
  Select-Object `
    Name,
    @{Name = "Volume"; Expression = { [Regex]::Match($_.Name, '\d+$').Value }},
    FreeSpaceGB |
  Sort-Object Volume -Descending
```

This code outputs the following:

```
Name       Volume FreeSpaceGB
----       ------ -----------
ABC-vol003 003    3147.135  
ABC-vol002 002    2345.437  
ABC-vol001 001    1474.201
```

So here we create a calculated property (custom column) in the output object containing the volume number (extracted using a regular expression), and sort by that.

Comment: I want to sort on `003` which is appended in name. That is why using `Sort {$_.Name -replace '.*?(\d+)$','$1'} -descending` I dont want to sort on `FreeSpaceGB`

Comment: To do that, you can change `Sort-Object { [Int] $_.FreeSpaceGB }` to `Sort-Object Name`.

Comment: If i do that i get `"ABC-volDAV","4147.135"` as output. I want to filter out values that don't have integer in the end such as `ABC-volDAV` before doing the sort so that I get correct result

Comment: Run the exact code I posted (with the change in my first comment). I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart `Sort-Object Name` would sort on the full name, including `ABC-`, whereas I think meallhour wants, for insance,  `XYZ-vol-003` to come before `ABC-vol-001`.

Comment: If that's the case, then the OP should clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever have more than 10 volumes?

```
Get-CustomCmdlet | ? Name -Notmatch ".*\d{3}$" | sort Name -Descending
```

Otherwise

```
Get-CustomCmdlet | ? Name -match ".*\d{3}$" | sort {[int]($_.Name -replace "\w{3}-\w{3}","")} -Descending
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add an answer that was more PowerShell-centric and had less regex-fu.

I only use regex in the filter for testing if a string is all numbers, because as far as I'm aware, there is no canned cmdlet or method in PowerShell to do this.

This will pipeline the example data, filter out anything without vol in the name, then test each one to make sure it only has numbers in the last three characters.  It does this by creating a variable of the last three characters ($matchString) using the .SubString method, then attempts to match it against the regex voodoo string, $filterMatchOnlyNumbers.

It will only pass on objects that match the filter.  Then it saves all of that into $results.

```
# example data set
$inputData = @"
"Name","FreeSpaceGB"
"ABC-vol001","1474.201"
"ABC-vol002","2345.437"     
"ABC-vol003","3147.135"
"ABC-volDAV","4147.135"
"ABC-volCDA","5147.135"
"ABC-volS4D","6147.135"
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

# regex voodoo to detect only numbers
$filterMatchOnlyNumbers = '^[\d\.]+$'

# filter to only return results that have "vol" in name
$nameFilter = '*vol*'

# do work and store to $results
$results = (
    $inputData |
    Where {$_.Name -like $nameFilter} |
    ForEach {
        # get last 3 characters of name
        $matchString = $_.Name.Substring($_.Name.Length - 3)

        If ($matchString -match $filterMatchOnlyNumbers){
            # pass this on if it is only numbers
            $_
        }
    }
)

# print results (only highest)
$results | Sort Name -Descending | Select Name -First 1
```

I saved the part of selecting only the "highest" result for last using a simple pipe to sort, then select.

"Sort Name -Descending" sorts it by name and sorts it in descending order so that the highest value will be first.

"Select Name" will only return the "Name" part of the objects in the pipeline, and "Select -First 1" will only return the first thing passed on in the pipe.

I know all of these answers are a little samey, but I wanted to provide an answer that was more powershelly and spaced out for any newbies coming along after this.

Comment: I forgot to add, for anyone else coming here for a similar answer, you can test if the last three characters contain ANY numbers by setting $filterMatchOnlyNumbers = '[0-9]'

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up on @Bill_Stewart's answer. It seems like it might be valuable to save the 'VolumeID' for later reference. This code adds it as a computed field through Select-Object, giving you a name to filter and sort on later in the pipeline.

```
$inputData = @"
"Name","FreeSpaceGB"
"ABC-vol001","1474.201"
"ABC-vol002","2345.437"
"ABC-vol003","3147.135"
"ABC-volDAV","4147.135"
"ABC-volCDA","5147.135"
"ABC-volS4D","6147.135"
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv


$inputdata | Select-Object -Property @(
        'Name'
        'FreeSpaceGB'
        @{l='VolumeID';e={$_.name -replace ".*-vol(.+).*",'$1'}}
    ) |
    Where-Object VolumeID -match "\d{3}" | 
    Sort-Object VolumeID | 
    Select-Object -Last 1
```

If you don't like the extra property being created during `Select-Object` you may want to make a function out of the regex filter for easy re-use:

```
function GetVolumeID {
    process { $_.Name -replace ".*-vol(.+).*",'$1' }
}

$inputData |
    Where-Object { ($_ | GetVolumeID) -match "\d{3}"} |
    Sort-Object { $_ | GetVolumeID } |
    Select-Object -Last 1
```